# Objective C: Exported Sqlite to Email has incomplete Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, messageui

I am trying to export the sqlite that I've created for core data to store the records locally to the app that I am developing.

I have managed to export the sqlite file via e-mail as attachment, but when I extracted the sqlite file the data is not complete, newly added records aren't shown.

Here's my code for export through e-mail,

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataModel.sqlite"];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *fileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0UL error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to read the file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        if (fileData == nil) {
            NSLog(@"File data is nil");
        }
    }

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if (mailView != nil) {
        mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailView setSubject:@"Records"];
        [mailView addAttachmentData:fileData
                           mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3"
                           fileName:@"CoreDataModel.sqlite"];

        [mailView setMessageBody:@"Database attached"
                          isHTML:NO];


        [self presentViewController:mailView animated:YES completion: NULL];

    }
```

Comment: Apparently, you have enabled [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).

Comment: @CL. How is that?

Comment: Read the page I linked to, especially about checkpointing.